# Understanding Mutual Information score between two variables

Tags: correlation, mutual-information

I have two variables - a target and a predictor. I want to capture the relationship between the two, but they are non-normal distributed, so I can't use correlation.

I remember a Data Science professor having us calculate Mutual Information since it can handle non-linear relationships and non-normal distributions.

But what would a MI of 0.4460503 mean here? I know there isn't a -1 to 1 scale like corr, but how would I interpret this?

Thanks!